# Windows 10 Search, Cortana, and Edge crashing

Tags: windows-10, crash, microsoft-edge, event-viewer, cortana

I have a relatively new install of Win10 Enterprise (Bitlocker enabled - hardware encryption with Samsung EVO 850 500 GB SSD) on a Lenovo T450s laptop, and despite having not set it up much yet for myself, I recently noticed that it's experiencing some major issues with SearchUI.exe and microsoftedgecp.exe (Microsoft Edge) - specifically that they are crashing due to edgehtml.dll (I think).  When you click on the start menu, it hesitates for a second before launching it, and you can't type to search for anything.  Clicking on Cortana does nothing, and Edge itself will crash within a few seconds of launching.  Here are a few of the event viewer entries:

-

```
Faulting application name: microsoftedgecp.exe, version: 11.0.10586.20, time stamp: 0x56540c35
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd3d95
Exception code: 0x88985004
Fault offset: 0x00000000004be12a
Faulting process id: 0x3bf0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18efa5270bbae
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoftedgecp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: 8d733596-7679-4146-a5bc-32e58b1a4129
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: MicrosoftEdge
```

-

```
Faulting application name: microsoftedgecp.exe, version: 11.0.10586.20, time stamp: 0x56540c35
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd3d95
Exception code: 0x88985004
Fault offset: 0x00000000004be12a
Faulting process id: 0x47c4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18efa51ded1e9
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoftedgecp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: c75874b5-d314-4b32-9abe-8f97492f1845
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: MicrosoftEdge
```

-

```
Faulting application name: microsoftedgecp.exe, version: 11.0.10586.20, time stamp: 0x56540c35
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd3d95
Exception code: 0x88985004
Fault offset: 0x00000000004be12a
Faulting process id: 0x1a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18efa510f8f66
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoftedgecp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: a2a299bd-ea1e-4f98-a430-6bdfb61e5109
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: MicrosoftEdge
```

-

```
Faulting application name: microsoftedgecp.exe, version: 11.0.10586.20, time stamp: 0x56540c35
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd3d95
Exception code: 0x88985004
Fault offset: 0x00000000004be12a
Faulting process id: 0x3640
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18efa510890c3
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoftedgecp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: db08f14e-8d55-49e4-b80c-3b9b56a21726
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: MicrosoftEdge
```

-

```
Faulting application name: SearchUI.exe, version: 10.0.10586.63, time stamp: 0x568b1fdc
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd3d95
Exception code: 0x88985004
Fault offset: 0x00000000004be12a
Faulting process id: 0x374c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18efa2d6609c6
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: 34230882-ec14-44b9-8ce0-1b4f30e59849
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.6.1.52_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

-

```
Fault bucket 133301214499, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.6.1.52_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
P2: praid:CortanaUI
P3: 10.0.10586.63
P4: 568b1fdc
P5: edgehtml.dll
P6: 11.0.10586.162
P7: 56cd3d95
P8: 88985004
P9: 00000000004be12a
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\<REDACTED>\AppData\Local\Temp\WER4DA8.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Window_897442cd215ce5bc4ce35642dc9bd6973fda99_00c55871_3150500a

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 34230882-ec14-44b9-8ce0-1b4f30e59849
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: eef41b25bfe514042d78e156ab16e2cf
```

I've tried SFC with no success, and the issue persists even on brand new different user accounts.  I've been scouring online trying to find a solution with no success either.  My next step is to perhaps try a Windows Repair, but would prefer to avoid that if possible - plus no guarantees it even fixes the issue.  Any thoughts/suggestions on what to try next?

Here is some additional information from Microsoft's forum: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/edgehtmldll-crashes-disable-searchui-and-edge/ed0f0fe8-e739-4900-80b3-121991bda5d4?page=1&tab=question&status=AllReplies

**UPDATE (4/6/16)**

Results from "sfc /scannow" and "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth"

```
C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\Windows\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10586.0

Image Version: 10.0.10586.0

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
```

**UPDATE-2 (4/6/16)**

Results from Process Monitor when launching Microsoft Edge (filtered for Path begins with C:\windows\fonts) :

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"5:40:51.5499877 PM","Explorer.EXE","4448","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts","SUCCESS",""
"5:40:51.5532395 PM","Explorer.EXE","4448","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:11.5068092 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.5069770 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","QueryInformationVolume","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","VolumeCreationTime: 2/21/2016 10:51:06 PM, VolumeSerialNumber: 1CE0-E6D8, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: "
"5:41:11.5070573 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","QueryAllInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","CreationTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:20 PM, LastAccessTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:20 PM, LastWriteTime: 10/30/2015 3:17:59 AM, ChangeTime: 4/6/2016 1:01:58 PM, FileAttributes: A, AllocationSize: 913,408, EndOfFile: 910,052, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x1400000001a87b, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word"
"5:41:11.5071492 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS","SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE|PAGE_NOCACHE"
"5:41:11.5072010 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 913,408, EndOfFile: 910,052, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False"
"5:41:11.5073179 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","SyncType: SyncTypeOther"
"5:41:11.5121628 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.5122610 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryInformationVolume","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","VolumeCreationTime: 2/21/2016 10:51:06 PM, VolumeSerialNumber: 1CE0-E6D8, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: "
"5:41:11.5123003 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryAllInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","CreationTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:20 PM, LastAccessTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:20 PM, LastWriteTime: 10/30/2015 3:17:59 AM, ChangeTime: 4/6/2016 1:01:58 PM, FileAttributes: A, AllocationSize: 913,408, EndOfFile: 910,052, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x1400000001a87b, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word"
"5:41:11.5123534 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS","SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE|PAGE_NOCACHE"
"5:41:11.5123869 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 913,408, EndOfFile: 910,052, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False"
"5:41:11.5124542 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","SyncType: SyncTypeOther"
"5:41:11.5126484 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Control, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.5127537 PM","svchost.exe","456","QuerySecurityFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","Information: DACL, DACL Unprotected"
"5:41:11.5128072 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:11.5129688 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Control, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.5130375 PM","svchost.exe","456","QuerySecurityFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Information: DACL, DACL Unprotected"
"5:41:11.5131821 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:11.7920593 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.7921820 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","QueryInformationVolume","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","VolumeCreationTime: 2/21/2016 10:51:06 PM, VolumeSerialNumber: 1CE0-E6D8, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: "
"5:41:11.7922503 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","QueryAllInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","CreationTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:37 PM, LastAccessTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:37 PM, LastWriteTime: 10/30/2015 3:18:01 AM, ChangeTime: 4/6/2016 1:01:58 PM, FileAttributes: A, AllocationSize: 802,816, EndOfFile: 802,408, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x70900000000a833, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word"
"5:41:11.7923204 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS","SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE|PAGE_NOCACHE"
"5:41:11.7923699 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 802,816, EndOfFile: 802,408, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False"
"5:41:11.7924721 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","SyncType: SyncTypeOther"
"5:41:11.7960577 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.7961492 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryInformationVolume","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","VolumeCreationTime: 2/21/2016 10:51:06 PM, VolumeSerialNumber: 1CE0-E6D8, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: "
"5:41:11.7961929 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryAllInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","CreationTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:37 PM, LastAccessTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:37 PM, LastWriteTime: 10/30/2015 3:18:01 AM, ChangeTime: 4/6/2016 1:01:58 PM, FileAttributes: A, AllocationSize: 802,816, EndOfFile: 802,408, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x70900000000a833, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word"
"5:41:11.7964009 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS","SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE|PAGE_NOCACHE"
"5:41:11.7964361 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 802,816, EndOfFile: 802,408, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False"
"5:41:11.7964973 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","SyncType: SyncTypeOther"
"5:41:11.7968181 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Control, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.7969056 PM","svchost.exe","456","QuerySecurityFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","Information: DACL, DACL Unprotected"
"5:41:11.7969498 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:11.7971336 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Control, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:11.7971948 PM","svchost.exe","456","QuerySecurityFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Information: DACL, DACL Unprotected"
"5:41:11.7972224 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:15.2784017 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:15.3094061 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:18.2358560 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:18.2359617 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryInformationVolume","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","VolumeCreationTime: 2/21/2016 10:51:06 PM, VolumeSerialNumber: 1CE0-E6D8, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: "
"5:41:18.2360139 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryAllInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","CreationTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:20 PM, LastAccessTime: 4/6/2016 5:39:20 PM, LastWriteTime: 10/30/2015 3:17:59 AM, ChangeTime: 4/6/2016 1:01:58 PM, FileAttributes: A, AllocationSize: 913,408, EndOfFile: 910,052, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x1400000001a87b, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word"
"5:41:18.2360733 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS","SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE|PAGE_NOCACHE"
"5:41:18.2361161 PM","svchost.exe","456","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 913,408, EndOfFile: 910,052, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False"
"5:41:18.2362000 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFileMapping","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","SyncType: SyncTypeOther"
"5:41:18.2363709 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Control, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:18.2364383 PM","svchost.exe","456","QuerySecurityFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","BUFFER OVERFLOW","Information: DACL, DACL Unprotected"
"5:41:18.2364673 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:18.2366396 PM","svchost.exe","456","CreateFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Control, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"
"5:41:18.2367159 PM","svchost.exe","456","QuerySecurityFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS","Information: DACL, DACL Unprotected"
"5:41:18.2367440 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:21.2377432 PM","svchost.exe","456","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:21.5793870 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
"5:41:21.5826254 PM","MicrosoftEdge.exe","16152","CloseFile","C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeuisl_1.ttf","SUCCESS",""
```

Comment: If you boot into a minimal configuration does the problem still happen?  A minimal configuration is, a configuration, with as little started automatically as possible but still have a functional system.  Autoruns is capable of disabling stuff that normally automatically starts to achieve this goal.  run SFC and DISM checks and submit the results into the question. "I've tried SFC with no success" - Tells us nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd3d95
Exception code: 0x88985004
```

The Exception code `0x88985004` means `DWRITE_E_FILEACCESS`

```
//
// MessageId: DWRITE_E_FILEACCESS
//
// MessageText:
//
// A font file exists but could not be opened due to access denied, sharing violation, or similar error.
//
#define DWRITE_E_FILEACCESS              _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x88985004L)
```

so, you have an issue with fonts (C:\Windows\Fonts).

ok, looking at the dump I see that Edge crashes while trying to load Times New Roman font. So I looked in the Process Monitor log and here I see that the Times New Roman font is not in C:\Windows\fonts, it is located in `C:\ProgramData\Samsung\SPenFonts` (`C:\ProgramData\Samsung\SPenFonts\Times.ttf`) and here Edge edge runs into `ACCESS DENIED` error. Edge has no permission to read the font:

[image]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

After this error, The Windows Error Reporting (`werfault.exe`) is launched and creates the error report (and creates the dump).

So look which Samsung software you have installed, that installs fonts to `C:\ProgramData`. If you figured out which software does this, remove that software from your device because the Times New Roman font is already part of Windows for ages. There is no need to install the font again.

Comment: Hmmm...ok, thanks - any suggestions on what to try to fix the issue?  Thanks again for the help so far!

Comment: run sfc /scannow and Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Comment: edited my original post above with the results of those two commands - neither seemed to find any issues though?

Comment: run process Monitor while trying to run Edge, filter for C:\Windows\Fonts access and look which font Edge tries to load.

Comment: So I found three font files that might be the culprits - all three are giving results of BUFFER OVERFLOW in process monitor.  They are segoeui.ttf, segoeuib.ttf, and segoeuisl.ttf.  So what would be the next step to fix these?  Thanks!

Comment: BUFFER OVERFLOW is fine. this is normal. Which other results do you see?

Comment: Damn, I thought that might have been it.  I actually replaced the three font files with ones from another Win10 machine that didn't have this issue, and now the fonts filenames are showing as segoeuib_1.ttf, segoeui_1.ttf, and segoeuisl_1.ttf once I replaced the original ones back (that I had backed up) - hope that won't cause any issues?? I'm going to put the full info from process monitor up above as an additional update/edit to my original post, but the only way I can figure out to do it is as a CSV - I can post the file somewhere though if that's easier for you. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: save the ProcessMonitor log as **PML**, zip the pml, uplod the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the share link here.

Comment: Here you go: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=846706FF60157340!5424&authkey=!AI-XoNzyy6-TyHU&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: this is the filtered PML. Sorry, I forgot to ask for an unfiltered one. also import this: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57 to generate a dump. Share the unfiltered PML + dmp file.

Comment: Sorry - haven't had a chance to do this yet, but will definitely get to it later tonight.  Thanks again very much for your help!!

Comment: So I have the unfiltered PML (320MB) and several dump files (totaling 966 MB) that I'm happy to share, but it occurs to me that I have no idea what's actually contained in these files.  I'd prefer not to place them on the Internet for everyone to access publicly - any way I can share them with you directly?  Hopefully that won't be a violation of this site's policies, and of course I'll continue to communicate on here with you so that everyone in the future will be able to see our troubleshooting efforts.  Let me know...?  Thanks again!

Comment: ok, I got the mail and added new details to the answer.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!  Uninstalling SNote (the culprit) did the trick and I'm working fully once again!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, showing:

> Access denied in C:\ProgramData\Samsung\SPenFonts\times.ttf

For that, the solution was uninstalling Samsung SNote.

Comment: Uninstalled SNote on my PC and the problem is fixed - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues for a few weeks with lots of apps crashing when they started.  It meant I couldn't enter my updated passwords for things like outlook as the thing they open to do that just crashed.  I couldn't use search, the time/calendar pop-up from the taskbar, couldn't add new users to the computer from the windows settings app.  The event logs all pointed to Exception code 0x88985004.  Tracing with procmon pointed to this being a problem opening fonts from a cache folder under my c:\users folder.

After days of searching I hit upon stopping and disabling the "Windows Font Cache Service" service.

Everything seems to work again and no problem with application performance that you're warned about in the service description.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! A friend had these same issues and your solution cleared the cache service and fixed it. The cache service restarted, but the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this was extremely helpful. I had FontBase running and accidentally activated a SegoeUI font which locked the system SegoeUI font. This caused Edge, edgecp, searchui/cortana, Calculator, Store, and several other UWP apps to crash. Upon closing FontBase or de-activating the SegoeUI font, things just started working again.

I diagnosed the access error by searching `font` in Process Monitor until I found a record that showed ACCESS DENIED to the SegoeUI font.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to this thread, was so helpful to diagnose a Windows Search crash and totally stopped working in Windows 11 after installing KB5006746 or KB5007215. The event viewer log was showing a 0x88985004 Exception Code pointing to edgehtml.dll with build 11.0.2200.282, the issue could be solved uninstalling the updates, but having a Zen 3 processor the slow L3 cache mitigation included was a must.

After following the tip to use Process Viewer to inspect the crash, found a bunch of records showing ACCESS DENIED in many fonts stored at C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\

> hit upon stopping and disabling the "Windows Font Cache Service"
> service

This was the solution, Windows Search worked again. Then cleared the cache at C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\FontCache , restarted the "Windows Font Cache Service" and Windows Search keeps working without crash.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092081)