# Windows 10 Search & Calendar stop working after font installation

Tags: windows-10, fonts, search, calendar, cortana

I've had this problem for a while that every once and so often, the Windows Search, Calendar, and other functions would stop working, and I had to return to a system restore point.

I now finally got a lead to what is causing this: This always happens after I install my personal collection of fonts, which I gathered over several decades now. I do not know which font or fonts cause this problem yet, though I was able to confirm that I can install individual fonts without causing this error.

If I find time, I'll try to figure out which of the 1700+ fonts in my collection cause this behavior. Until then, I'll just stick to installing the fonts one-by-one on a need-basis.

Has anyone else observed this behavior? I've run across these symptoms on a number of other threads, but none of them seemed to be linked to fonts, or at least none were traced to fonts. The funny thing is that up to a certain point in June, everything worked just fine for me even with my full collection of fonts installed.

Does anyone have any idea on what could be causing this, or maybe on ideas how to track down which font(s) cause this behavior? Thus far my best thought is using a binary search pattern, but that would involve using System Restore a LOT of times, which is not really something I look forward to.

By the way, here's also the logs that appear in the event log after the error activates, and whenever I try to use the Search or Calendar afterwards:

Error in Event Log whenever Search App Crashes:

```
Faulting application name: SearchApp.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1110, time stamp: 0xa6e985d6
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1110, time stamp: 0x4809adf2
Exception code: 0x88985004
Fault offset: 0x000000000010bd3e
Faulting process ID: 0x152c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d77cb71a053e34
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: 9c7575de-840d-4596-b862-0e998a0945e4
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.Search_1.14.2.19041_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: CortanaUI
```

When calendar crashes:

```
Faulting application name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.19041.610, time stamp: 0x5d4af3f4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1110, time stamp: 0x4809adf2
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x000000000010bd3e
Faulting process ID: 0x4288
Faulting application start time: 0x01d77cba55877d81
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: c7c3cc84-57bc-4f83-95b9-b5d3f18c1c2b
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.19041.1023_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

AND I also get a message that something is wrong with Cortana after every System Restore, though the error message is very generic and doesn't feature any technical details.

By the way, I also already did a full repair install and all that, and that doesn't fix the error when it appears. Only returning to a System Restore Point helps.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1061514/windows-10-search-cortana-and-edge-crashing

Comment: Try making a new User Account and see if Search works properly in the new User Account.

Comment: @John : Yes, that's what I did before, but then it started happening on the new account as well, which is when I started using system restore instead because that's faster than migrating everything to a new account every two weeks or so.

Comment: If a repair install did not work and a new User Profile did not work, it may be best and fastest to back up and reinstall Windows.